# jEasy UI Messenger Change Button Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using jEasy UI Framework for my project.
I am using  `$.messager.confirm` to get a confirmation from the user.

Which shows two buttons `OK` and `Cancel`.

How can i change button text when i am  using `$.messager.confirm` ?

Example:

```
'ok' => 'yes',
'cancel' => 'no'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.messager.defaults.ok = 'Yes';
$.messager.defaults.cancel = 'No';
```

These are the two lines which will be need to change the text property of the prompt messenger in jEasy UI

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

$.messager.defaults = { ok: "Yes", cancel: "No" };